# Mutually Dependent Events

Tags: probability

Just came across this term "Mutually Dependent Events". I've never come across this before and can't seem to find a definition for it. Is it the same as dependent events?

Comment: *NOT* mutually independent events.

Comment: The statement that events A,B,C are *mutually dependent* is simply a shorthand way of saying that A,B are not independent events, B,C are not independent events, and A,C are not independent events.